# C++ Error passing a 2D array to function?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

EDIT: ROW and COLUMN are int values, ROW = 12, COLUMN = 2

```
int main() {
   double list[ROW][COLUMN];

   ifstream inFile;
   getValidDataFile(inFile);
   cout << "Temperature Data for the year " << getYear(inFile) << endl;

   getData(inFile, list[][COLUMN], ROW); // Error Line


   return 0;
}
```

Error: "error: expected primary-expression before ']' token"
I need to get the data from the file and store it in a 2d array.
BTW this is a homework assignment

```
void getData(ifstream& fin, double a[][COLUMN], int ROW) {
    int row, col;
    double num;
    for(row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < COLUMN; col++) {
            fin >> num;
            a[row][col] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ROW`/`COLUMN` are what actually? Ask for code and errors providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please!

Answer (score 2):

When you call getData() you should pass in the array without specifying the dimensions.  After the declaration list[X][Y] will access an individual element in row X column Y.

```
getData(inFile, list, row);
```

Also, it is recommended to only use UPPERCASE for macros, not function parameters:

```
void getData(ifstream& fin, double a[][COLUMN], int input_row) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just mention the maximum size of the column size while declaring and defining the function,and as usual you pass base address of the array to function

```
void print(int p_arr[][10]); //max size of the column   -- declaration
int g_row,g_column;//make it as these variables as global;
int main()
{
   int l_arr[10][10];//local array
   printf("Enter row value and column value");
   scanf("%d%d",&g_row,&g_column);
   for(int i=0;i<g_row;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<g_column;j++)
      {
         scanf("%d",&l_arr[i][j]);
      }
   }
   print(l_arr);//you just pass the array address to the function
   return 0;
}
void print(int p_arr[][10])
{
   for(int i=0;i<g_row;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<g_column;j++)
      {
         printf("%d\t",p_arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be easier to pass it as a double pointer with row and col information. So your code would be

```
void getData(ifstream *fin, double** a, int row, int col);
```

The function definition will remain the same

```
 getData(inFile, list, row, col);
```

is the way to use it.

Comment: I wanted to do it that way, but my course manager gives us specific instructions on how to construct our functions.